# HTML Agility Pack for Delphi

Tags: html, delphi, html-agility-pack, delphi-xe2

Which is the most close replacement of HTML Agility Pack for Delphi. I need some HTML being stripped and the ability to build a DOM tree over a loosely formated HTML.

Comment: Do you mean the HTML Agility Pack? There is no "MS Agility Pack".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DIHtmlParser from Delphi Inspiration might suit you:  http://www.yunqa.de/delphi/doku.php/products/htmlparser/index

Answer (score 0):

TidyPas works (http://sourceforge.net/projects/curlpas/files/). It is based on HTML tidy so it works well for ill-formed HTML. I have been using it for about 5 years and even updated the code to handle Unicode Delphi versions.

Comment: Have your Unicode fixes been added to the sourceforce?

Comment: Yes they have - I uploaded the changes myself